# Standard Deviation Likelihood

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, maximum-likelihood

> Suppose $Y_i$ i.i.d $N(0,\sigma^2)$, i = 1, ..., n. Derive the likelihood for $\sigma$.

$L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \Pi_{i=1}^n f(X_i | \mu, \sigma^2) 
$

$= \Pi_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-(X_i-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}$

However, I am lost how to get rid of the $\mu$ term and just derive $\sigma$. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In your setting, $\mu=0$ since the mean of each $Y_i = 0$

$$L(\sigma^2) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-(X_i)^2/2\sigma^2}$$

Edit:

$$L(\sigma^2) =  \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2})^n}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i)^2/2\sigma^2}$$

Comment: Hm, ok, and then how do you isolate the sigma term?

Comment: Do you mean how to get rid of the product term?

Comment: Yes, I'm a little confused as to how to get rid of it. Is it not just throwing the n on top? And then, from there, how do you isolate the sigma term?

Comment: Try to solve some warm up questions first: Try to evaluate $\prod_{i=1}^n 2$ and $2^2\cdot 2^3$. Then look at it again, and give it another try?

Comment: Alright, so you raise it to the nth power....

Comment: I edited my solution, note that the exponent is dependent on the index $i$.